# Solr Suggester - dynamic or passed at runtime field

Tags: solr, lucene

Is it possible to have dynamic field or pass field for suggestions at runtime (in query for example) for SuggestComponent?

Depending on user's language I would like to suggest him different things. I have dynamic field `name_*` that has concrete fields: `name_pl`, `name_de` and `name_en` (can be more, I want to have flexibility here) and I would like to search for suggestions depending on language: for pl I want to get suggestions in `name_pl`, for en in `name_en` and so on.

So far I have standard Suggester with field specified:

```
      <searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="dictionaryImpl">HighFrequencyDictionaryFactory</str>
      <str name="">name_pl</str>

      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
      <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>

  <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler"
                  startup="lazy" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="suggest">true</str>
      <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

But actually I need either to use `name_*` or preferably at runtime to pass the field name for example: http://localhost:8983/solr/services/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&suggest.q=name&**suggest.field=name_pl**

How would you implement such mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It is not the answer you may expect but I started a comment and I ended up with this.*

By using a dynamic field here you would have to rebuild the suggester at each query, I suggest ;) you require a specific suggestComponent' dictionary on query.

The value for `field` should remain static because it is parsed once to build a dictionary index from that field. Or you would have to delete/rebuild that index each time a suggest query requires a dictionary other than the one previously built.

Instead you should replicate the suggester definition for each language you may have so that Solr can build one dictionary index per field/language (just name the suggesters according to the target field language) :

```xml
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">suggest_nl</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">HighFrequencyDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">name_pl</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
    <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
  </lst>
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">suggest_en</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">HighFrequencyDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">name_en</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
    <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
  </lst>
  <!-- etc. -->
</searchComponent>
```

Now you can query the target dictionary dynamically :

```
.../suggest?suggest=true&suggest.q=name&suggest.dictionary=suggest_nl
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to do this, not sure if you are aware of it:

1. you create one dictionary per language: suggester_pl, suggester_en...each using the right field. They are all defined inside a single SuggestComponent
2. when calling, you select which one to hit with &suggest.dictionary=suggester_en

check the docs [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/suggester.html)